# Making Cursor as a Hammer Animation ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, cursor, movieclip

I made a custom cursor -as a hammer and want to run an animation when I click the button. When the user clicks any buttons, hammer will hit(hammer) the button. I used 2 key frames in Cursor() class to make hammer animation and use several ways to implement it in my program -like gotoAndStop(), play() etc. But nothing works...

So, if you show me a way to solve this problem, I'll be very appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
var menuCursor:MovieClip = new Cursor();
Mouse.hide();
menuCursor.mouseEnabled = false;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cursorMenuMove);
menuCursor.gotoAndStop(1);
function cursorMenuMove(event:Event )
{
    menuCursor.x = mouseX;
    menuCursor.y = mouseY;
}

.
.
.

howToImageOn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, run1HowTo );

.
.
.

function run1HowTo( event:MouseEvent )
{
       menuCursor.gotoAndStop(2);
   //    or   menuCursor.play();
    whackSound.play(0,1);
    menuMusicChannel.stop();
    howToImageOn.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, howTo1Out );
    playImageOff.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, play1Over );
    creditsImageOff.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, credits1Over );
    removeChild( playImageOff );
    removeChild(howToImageOn);
    removeChild( creditsImageOff);
    removeChild( menuCursor );
    gotoAndStop( "HowToPlay" );
}
```

Comment: I don't know how... but it always remains same... If ActionScript has something like yield in Unity, it may solve the problem. I stop the program and play the animation. After continue to program. Does this work and does ActionScript has something like yield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using this code:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, up);

function down(e:MouseEvent){
    menuCursor.gotoAndStop(2);
}

function up(e:MouseEvent){
    menuCursor.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never liked using gotoAndStop and gotoAndPlay, so I've been always doing this that way:

Create first MovieClip/Sprite which contains not-animated version of your cursor and second one which contains animated version (looped animation), and in your custom class Cursor which should extend MovieClip just switch between them - remove first one, add second one - for ex. after click. This way allows you to simply add more cursor types (and animations) easily, and even easier switch between them :)

Comment: It's a good idea Chev but there will be a lot of addChild/removeChild. I think this causes decreasing in performans, right?

Comment: I don't think that adding and removing child would highly decrease the performance of your application, especially when you are doing this not so often. The idea makes it easier to switch between them while you are programming. It's just using something like cursor.changeCursor(Cursor.POINTER). 

Here is some interesting read: [Actionscript.org Forum](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=230294)